# How to express that the temperature is high?

Tags: word-choice

Saying somebody is hot seems to mean somebody is sexy. So how would one express that the temperature is high? Is "I feel hot" OK?

Comment: You feel feverish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hot may means different things so you should give some more information about your current situation to make yourself more clear to your partner in the conversation .

**temperature** -Being at a high temperature

> Is is hot here or it is just me.
>
> I think I am getting sweaty, it is so hot here.

Comment: Does "_it is so hot here_" mean "_it is so sexy here_" as well?

Comment: Good point, well I haven't been to sexy places (see **here**), but I have been with sexy people. It can mean sexy but it will refer to something of the context- see that song:Effortless fly, that's when I lean in close to mention girl...

[Chorus:]
Maybe it's you (I don't know...) maybe it's me (mmmm...)
But for whatever reason, it just got sexy in here.

Answer (score 2):

It's how you say it. If you're in the position of having to use that expression then say "I'm feeling overheated." *Sexy* and *hot* are two very different things as well.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the words may have multiple meanings.  Hot, for example, may refer to **temperature**, **sexual desire / sexuality** or **spicy**.  Context - the situation a word used in - mostly makes the meaning intended more clear. E.g:

> Don't you feel hot so close to the fire.
>
> She is hot and beautiful.
>
> I love really hot food.

So, your sentence  "**I feel hot**" would not be clear without context. You can say **The weather is a little hot for me**.

Comment: Ur use _warm_ perhaps

Answer (score 0):

It is a complex problem. If you are draped over someone, and say in a sultry voice "I feel HOT", then it has a very clear sexual meaning. However, even if you say it with the intention of meaning "the temperature is higher than I am comfprtable with", if the context is right, could be misinterpreted.

The obvious approach is to say "it's quite warm in here", but, once again, if you say this to a person of appropriate gender, it can be interpreted as an offer to go somewhere else and do something else......

Often it is easiest to suggest a remedy instead - "could we open a window". Of course, if the person you are talking to thinks you are hot then they may choose to misinterpret anything you say.

Answer (score 0):

Understatement can help resolve this particular ambiguity, e.g.

> I feel warm.

If the point you want to make is that you're feeling uncomfortably hot, then say so explicitly, e.g.

> I feel too hot.
>
> It's too hot.